# Print a different element from list but with same text and increasing number?

Tags: python, list

I want to print it starting from "Francisco" and ending with "Antonio", but keeping text with the numbers increasing, I really don't know where to go with this, I'm very new, thank you for helping!

```
list = ['Francisco', 'Marcelle', 'Olivia', 'José', 'Guilherme', 'Maria', 'Arthur', 'Lucas', 'Lurdes', 'Antonio']    

for x in range(1,11) :
    print(list[x] "your number on the list is, " + str(x) + ".")
```

In the last line I found how to keep text, add increasing number but I don't know how to print different element with range, for, I started programming not long

Example:
Francisco, your number is 1,
Marcelle, your number is 2,
Antonio, your number is 10

Comment: Use `enumerate`, as shown in [Accessing the index in 'for' loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of mistakes that you make here, some of the more code breaking than others. I'll list them here.

1. First of don't just the list name as a variable name, e.g. change **list** to **list_of_names**. The list namespace is already used by python, as the list class [see here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).
2. list start from 0. You start from 1 and run to 11. Therefore you will list index will run of of range. Change the for loop to either

```
for i, name in enumerate(list_of_names):
```

Here `i` already has the number and `name` has the name.

You could use that in the print statement.

or

```
for i in range(len(list_of_names)):
```

3. The print statement is not formatted correctly, one way to do better formatting is by using the f-string.

```
print(f"{list[x]} your number on the list is, {str(x)}.")
```

all of this will result in the following code piece added together.

```
list_of_names = ['Francisco', 'Marcelle', 'Olivia', 'José', 'Guilherme', 'Maria', 'Arthur', 'Lucas', 'Lurdes', 'Antonio']
for x in range(len(list_of_names)):
     print(f"{list[x]} your number on the list is, {str(x+1)}.")
```

Good luck learning!

Answer (score 0):

Is the below what you are looking for?

```
names = ['Francisco', 'Marcelle', 'Olivia', 'José', 'Guilherme', 'Maria', 'Arthur', 'Lucas', 'Lurdes', 'Antonio']
for idx, name in enumerate(names, 1):
    print(f'{name}, your number is {idx}')
```

output

```
Francisco, your number is 1
Marcelle, your number is 2
Olivia, your number is 3
José, your number is 4
Guilherme, your number is 5
Maria, your number is 6
Arthur, your number is 7
Lucas, your number is 8
Lurdes, your number is 9
Antonio, your number is 10
```

Comment: Like this: (Francisco, your number is 1) to (Antonio your number is 10), thanks for helping me!

Comment: Henry - do you want to try and modify the code example and adopt it to your needs? It can be valuable for you.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm doing now, thank you very much, C:

Comment: @HenryGabriel great. In case you are having issues have a look at the latest code.

Comment: Now I understand, you helped me a lot sir!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to print:
Francisco your number on the list is: 1
Marcelle your number on the list is: 2
Olivia your number on the list is: 3
José your number on the list is: 4
Guilherme your number on the list is: 5
Maria your number on the list is: 6
Arthur your number on the list is: 7
Lucas your number on the list is: 8
Lurdes your number on the list is: 9
Antonio your number on the list is: 10
If is it the case then you can use this code:

```
L = ['Francisco', 'Marcelle', 'Olivia', 'José', 'Guilherme', 'Maria', 
   'Arthur', 'Lucas', 'Lurdes', 'Antonio']    

for i in range (len(L)):
print(L[i],"your number on the list is:",i+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close to the correct code which is

```
list = ['Francisco', 'Marcelle', 'Olivia', 'José', 'Guilherme', 'Maria', 'Arthur', 'Lucas', 'Lurdes', 'Antonio']    

for x in range(0,len(list)) :
    print(list[x] + " your number on the list is " + str(x) + ".")
```

**Modifications from yours**

What you did wrong :

- you forgot the + of concatenation in `list[x] + " your number on the list is "`
- you started at the index 1 in `range`, but lists start at index 0

What I improved :

- in the range, if you don't know in advance the length of list, use `len(list)`

Have fun discovering Python and practising! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do that using `enumerate()` with `start` argument set to 1 (*Since you need to start counting from 1*).

*Note: Don't use `list` as variable names. That's a python reserved word.*

```
lst = ['Francisco', 'Marcelle', 'Olivia', 'José', 'Guilherme', 'Maria', 'Arthur', 'Lucas', 'Lurdes', 'Antonio']
for i,v in enumerate(lst,start=1):
    print(f'{v}, your number is {i}')
```

```
Francisco, your number is 1
Marcelle, your number is 2
Olivia, your number is 3
José, your number is 4
Guilherme, your number is 5
Maria, your number is 6
Arthur, your number is 7
Lucas, your number is 8
Lurdes, your number is 9
Antonio, your number is 10
```